# How can I make this model more efficient?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder

[image: Yield Analysis]

The issue I am running into is when the amount of data scales up the model takes a very long time to process.  The step that seems to be bogging down the model is the extract by mask portions while the rest of the model seems to run at about what I would expect.  My thought is that there is some processing extents or some environmental setting I am missing.  A snip of the execution shows the rough times it takes to process each step.

[image]

Comment: What type of raster data are you working with? What bit depth? Does the processing time increase cumulatively as the model progresses, indicating a memory issue? Have you tried working with `in_memory` workspace?

Comment: I am working with raw yield data in the form of a point shapefile and then they are being converted into rasters using the IDW tool.  The different steps in the process all take about the same time with the exception of the mask portion which takes quite a bit more time than the other steps for instance the IDW part takes 20 seconds on a given field while the Mask will take 5 minutes or more.  I have not tried in_memory workspace.

Comment: What bit depth are you saving the raster data? Use lowest bit depth and spatial resolution possible for your data. Try running this using in_memory temporary workspace: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm.

Comment: ...One more question: are you reading/writing over a network drive or locally on your computer?

Comment: I am doing this over a network which I know inflates the time taken to process a good deal, but I was also having this issue on my local drive.